# Why I can't import PowerShell Module?

Tags: windows, powershell

For example I used Install-Module TestModule, it asked me questions and I press Yes After I tried Import-Module TestModule

```
Import-Module : The specified module 'TestModule' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any
module directory.
At line:1 char:1
+ Import-Module TestModule
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (TestModule :String) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
```

Comment: What question did it ask you? What happens if you run `Get-Modules`, is it listed?

Comment: Get-Modules : The term 'Get-Modules' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-Modules
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-Modules:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: In addition don't add the `s`, it's just `Get-Module`. You will also need to add `-ListAvailable`. But I guess you're rather new to PS?

Comment: Cant post here Get-Module -ListAvailable cause message is too long, but the package I need is not listed

Comment: See this [Article](https://winaero.com/blog/fix-install-module-missing-powershell/)